# Batch email delivery with Mailgun and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, api, email, batch-file, mailgun

Our site is Wordpress based, and we use Mailgun plugin to send emails to our customers. So we will start a campaign this week, where we need to send about 200K emails, my question is: Does Mailgun plugin for Wordpress use batch feature at API level?

Best regards,
Oscar.

Answer (score -1):

If you download blat from (http://www.blat.net/) you can use the command line to send emails.

1. Place blat into C:\WINDOWS\System32
2. Before you can email you have to configure blat with:

   ```
   blat -install smtp.whateverserver.com youremail@somewhere.com -u youremail@somewhere.com -pw mypassword – –
   ```
3. Now you can send an email with:

   ```
   blat -p -to "recipient" -subject "subject" -body "bodymessage"
   ```

   Im not sure if this answers your question but i hope it does.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question at all. You are just promoting an alternative you found useful. SO isn't for recommendations. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: sorry im new to stackoverflow